# What type of paint and how many coats should be used to paint a radiator?

Tags: painting, paint, radiator, repainting

We've moved into a new house with a fairly incompatible sense of interior design. To illustrate one room in particular, the walls are orange, the floor to ceiling shelves are orange, the fireplace mantle is orange, the pinboard is orange and the radiator is orange.

The entire room looks like it's been painted in the same shade of orange and possibly even the same type of paint.

[image]

I'd like to re-paint the walls and the radiator but I'm new to painting radiators and I'm not sure where to start. I'm mainly concerned about what type of paint to use and how many coatings should be applied.

Comment: What kind of radiator?

Comment: @kavisiegel: I don't know but [I took a picture](http://i.imgur.com/B1MGI.jpg) in case it was relevant.

Comment: Do you know if it is steam or hot water? Steam would run at a higher temperature and maybe need a different treatment.  Are pipes running into it on both ends?

Answer (score 9):

If we're talking a cast iron radiator, it's a good process.

First you need to remove the old finish. You can get it sandblasted, or you can get in there with some sandpaper for a few hours. A wire wheel on an angle grinder can get out a good bit, or you might have luck with chemicals to strip them. If you do use chemicals, you'll have to wait for them to totally dry, then sand the bare metal of the radiator just to make 100% sure all of the residue is gone and the surface is rough enough.

Next, you'll want to clean with a deglosser, to make sure all the sanding residue is gone, along with any other junk in there. The paint won't bond so well without it, and with something that expands and contracts as much as a heater.. you want to make sure it's thoroughly clean.

Now it's time to protect your walls and floors. Get a drop cloth, cut a slit in it and slide it over the unit. Tape it to the walls, tape it to the floor, and tape up as much of the slit you made as you can.

You'll then need to prime it, and you'll have to chose the primer based on the paint you end up with.

Time for paint. Oil based paint should hold up, but you'll probably have better luck with spray enamel paint. Use many thin coats rather than few thick coats. Make sure to read the specs on whatever paint you decide on, make sure it can withstand up to 220 degrees - Just to be safe.

Alternatively, maybe you can look into building a radiator cover.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work. I hadn't considered a radiator cover, that's a good suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Given how cheap radiators are (expect a 80% discount from list price), I would just replace them.

I do not know of a paint that will last a long time on a radiator,  also however good your new paint is, it will fail, as soon as the orange paint fails.

Answer (score -3):

On "Rehab Addict," Nicole just paints old BROKEN radiators with metallic spray paint in a can.  I think 2 cans per radiator?

Comment: Nope: you need high-heat paint for radiators.